# Syntax error mysql

Tags: mysql

Where is the syntax error in this statement? I dont get it, can I use the "? bind param method" in this case? I use PDO

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO epinfo WHERE TVShowTitle=? (Season, Episode, SDLink, HDLink, DlSDLink, DlHDLink) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST[tvshow]);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST[season]);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST[episode]);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST[sdlink]);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST[hdlink]);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $_POST[dlsdlink]);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $_POST[dlhdlink]);
$stmt->execute();

Error message:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE TVShowTitle='Breaking Bad' (Season, Episode, SDLink, HDLink, DlSDLink, DlH' at line 1
```

Comment: Do you want to update an existing record?

Comment: Your where clause doesn't make sense. You're probably looking to UPDATE instead of INSERT

Comment: Put you "where" clause at the end. Look up MySQL syntax for doing this.

Comment: True, I want to update the values ill try to make an update statement insted. Thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation on the correct syntax of the `INSERT` statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @daniel a where clause after VALUES wouldn't make things better

Comment: @Conrad Frix - Yep .. overlooked the INSERT. A tip for the OP. Try to hard-code your sql statements in phpmyadmin or other database management software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `INSERT` syntax has no `WHERE` clause. I think you want to `UPDATE` your existing record.

```
UPDATE epinfo 
SET Season = ?, 
    Episode = ?, 
    SDLink = ?, 
    HDLink = ?, 
    DlSDLink = ?, 
    DlHDLink = ?
WHERE TVShowTitle=?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO epinfo (TVShowTitle, Season, Episode, SDLink, HDLink, DlSDLink, DlHDLink) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the where clause.

from here

```
  INSERT INTO epinfo WHERE
```

Try like this:-

```
 INSERT INTO epinfo(Season, Episode, SDLink, HDLink, DlSDLink, DlHDLink) 
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

From your comments:

If you want to update the value then use it like this:-

```
update epinfo
set column = "value"
where TVShowTitle=?
```